# multiple columns from database resultset - Display bargraph using google charts

Tags: javascript, jsp, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a bar graph with x-axis as date and y-axis as count for different channels. Here below is my code and when i run it, I am not seeing anything on the page. Is this right way to do this? please let me know

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %> 
    <%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var theData = [ // Start of JavaScript data object
            <%
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver").newInstance();
            String connectionURL = "somestring";
            Connection connection = null;
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);

                PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT TO_CHAR(order_date, 'dd-Mon-yy') order_date, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'CAE', acctnum, NULL)) AS cae, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'COM', acctnum, NULL)) AS com, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'COMPRO', acctnum, NULL)) AS compro, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'EBIF', acctnum, NULL)) AS ebif, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'FRC', acctnum, NULL)) AS frc, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'IVR', acctnum, NULL)) AS ivr, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'NATPRO', acctnum, NULL)) AS natpro, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'PRO', acctnum, NULL)) AS pro, COUNT(DECODE(order_channel, 'X1U', acctnum, NULL)) AS x1u FROM order_channel WHERE order_date >= TRUNC(sysdate) - 30 GROUP BY order_date ORDER BY TO_DATE(order_date)");
                ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

                while (rs.next()) {
            %>
                    [" <%= rs.getString(1)%>",<%= rs.getString(2)%>",<%= rs.getString(3)%>",<%= rs.getString(4)%>",<%= rs.getString(5)%>",<%= rs.getString(6)%>",<%= rs.getString(7)%>",<%= rs.getString(8)%>",<%= rs.getString(9)%>",<%= rs.getString(10)%>"],
            <%
                };
                // End of JavaScript object holding the data
            %>
                ];
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
           function drawChart() {
                var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['OrderDate', 'CAE', 'Com','ComPro','EBIF','FRC','IVR','NAT','PRO','X1U']].concat(theData), false);

                var options = {
                    title: 'National 30 days'
                };
                var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, options);
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the data which i getting from backend by sql..

```
var theData = [ // Start of JavaScript data object

                    [ "08-May-16",9,0,0,68,50,1,4,7,0],

                    [ "09-May-16",7,0,0,84,175,0,14,37,0],

                    [ "10-May-16",7,0,0,67,170,0,9,46,0],

                    [ "11-May-16",7,0,0,53,164,0,7,42,0],

                    [ "12-May-16",7,0,0,63,146,0,3,41,0],

                    [ "13-May-16",7,0,0,114,165,0,7,36,0],

                    [ "14-May-16",7,1,0,69,135,0,7,32,0],

                    [ "15-May-16",1,0,0,76,62,0,4,11,0],

                    [ "16-May-16",14,8,0,62,156,0,13,49,0],

                    [ "17-May-16",8,17,0,48,149,0,5,48,2],

                    [ "18-May-16",7,0,0,58,146,0,3,40,2],

                    [ "19-May-16",3,0,0,49,140,0,6,36,0],

                    [ "20-May-16",9,2,0,56,158,0,1,40,1],

                    [ "21-May-16",6,0,0,54,147,0,5,40,4],

                    [ "22-May-16",5,0,0,69,57,0,2,13,0],

                    [ "23-May-16",7,0,0,61,178,0,11,69,5],

                    [ "24-May-16",10,5,0,76,162,0,9,56,4],

                    [ "25-May-16",34,0,0,841,159,0,5,41,4],

                    [ "26-May-16",41,0,0,1206,85,0,4,21,0],

                    [ "27-May-16",56,0,0,745,216,0,10,36,2],

                    [ "28-May-16",94,1,0,198,146,0,9,30,2],

                    [ "29-May-16",66,0,0,12,67,0,3,7,0],

                    [ "30-May-16",59,0,0,876,46,0,6,17,0],

                    [ "31-May-16",140,4,0,2187,203,0,19,42,2],

                    [ "01-Jun-16",43,0,0,1029,147,0,95,47,0],

                    [ "02-Jun-16",136,18,0,941,510,0,260,163,11],

                    [ "03-Jun-16",79,0,0,462,446,0,146,116,9],

                    [ "04-Jun-16",29,1,0,669,387,0,83,81,0],

                    [ "05-Jun-16",45,0,0,791,215,0,36,48,5],

                    [ "06-Jun-16",111,0,0,643,478,0,238,159,8],

                    [ "07-Jun-16",3,0,0,170,12,0,0,0,0],

                ];
```

Comment: This is the error Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string×

Comment: I am not sure googlecharts will work for more than 2 columns as my sql query return 10 columns in a row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like there are some extra quotation marks

try replacing...

```
[" <%= rs.getString(1)%>",<%= rs.getString(2)%>",<%= rs.getString(3)%>",<%= rs.getString(4)%>",<%= rs.getString(5)%>",<%= rs.getString(6)%>",<%= rs.getString(7)%>",<%= rs.getString(8)%>",<%= rs.getString(9)%>",<%= rs.getString(10)%>"],
```

with...

```
["<%= rs.getString(1)%>",<%= rs.getString(2)%>,<%= rs.getString(3)%>,<%= rs.getString(4)%>,<%= rs.getString(5)%>,<%= rs.getString(6)%>,<%= rs.getString(7)%>,<%= rs.getString(8)%>,<%= rs.getString(9)%>,<%= rs.getString(10)%>],
```

Comment: Bars of bargraph appearing very thin even after setting the option bar: {groupWidth: "95%"} and also how i can shuffle the axis. I want to show date on x-axis and count on y axis but the graph displaying it in reverse way

Comment: Edit my question - added data

Comment: I see what you mean -- to _shuffle the axis_, use `.ColumnChart` vs. `.BarChart` -- but there is so much data, `groupWidth` won't have much effect. you could try using [configuration-options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart#configuration-options) `isStacked: true` -- or -- `explorer` which allows the user to zoom-in by selecting a range

Comment: Great help! Thanks

Comment: My barchart showing minimized when i show it under Tabs for some reason. any clues??

Comment: if you draw while hidden -- need to set specific `height` & `width` -- or wait until it is shown before drawing...

Comment: I am getting this error while create a Linechart with sql data - Error: ReferenceError: CAE is not defined
 

[ "January 16",CAE,18],

 
Nationa...ers.jsp (line 11, col 36)
Error: Invalid row type for row 0

Comment: Can you please throw some light on this. Here is the separate thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753643/googlecharts-error-invalid-row-type-for-row-0